# How to set vertically center text in tables and add enters when using tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx

How do I vertically center text in the tables, such as "Author 1 (Year)" and how do I add enters between words in tables so that the text comes under each other, like with the words War, Revolution and Civil disorders?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Three levels of political risks} 
\label{tab:rcpol}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
\toprule 
\textbf{References} & \textbf{Macro risks} & \textbf{Meso risks} & \textbf{Micro risks}  \\
\midrule
Author 1 (Year)       
    &  Corruption   
        &  Government intervention
             &  Expropriation; 
                Nationalisation of assets
    \\ \midrule
Author 2 (Year)     
    &  War; Revolution; Civil disorders
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth
                          \centering\arraybackslash}X}{%
        Inconsistent government policies } 
    \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: you should consider empty lines in cells as i show in my answers (from where you adopt showed code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an `X` type column you can use `\linebreak` to insert line breaks. Inside a normal cell, you can use a `\begin{tabular}{@{} <col> @{}}<content>\end{tabular}` construct to insert line breaks (or use `\makecell` from the `makecell` package, that does the same).

If you want to use the definition of `\\` as it would be inside a `\centering` environment, you could as well use `>{\centering\let\mynewline\\\arraybackslash}X` in your preamble and in your table use `\mynewline` instead of `\linebreak`.

As for the vertical alignment of `X` type cells: You can change the definition of `\tabularxcolumn` to use `m` instead of `p` type columns for vertically centred content.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% change the column type of tabularx to use `m` instead of `p` for the vertical
% centering:
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Three levels of political risks} 
\label{tab:rcpol}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
\toprule 
\textbf{References} & \textbf{Macro risks} & \textbf{Meso risks} & \textbf{Micro risks}  \\
\midrule
Author 1 (Year)       
    &  Corruption   
        &  Government intervention
             &  Expropriation; 
                Nationalisation of assets
    \\ \midrule
Author 2 (Year)     
    &  War; Revolution; Civil disorders
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth
                          \centering\arraybackslash}X}{%
        Inconsistent government policies } 
    \\ 
    author & En-\linebreak forcing\linebreak line\linebreak breaks 
    \\
    \begin{tabular}[]{@{}c@{}}
      line\\breaks\\in\\a\\normal\\cell
    \end{tabular}
    & other cell & other cell
    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\arrrayrulewidth` is zero, so it can be omitted in calculation of column width (as pointed @Mico to my answer from where op take code) :-)

Comment: @Zarko might be true, but it might not always be zero and therefore I don't think it does any harm to keep it in the calculation.

Comment: you are right, i only mentioned that code be can shorter for one symbol and one word :-)